# We can write a positive rational number $q$ in form : $ q=\dfrac{a^3+b^3}{m^2+n^2}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For $a,b,c,m,n$  are positive integers, prove that: We can write a positive rational number $q$ in form : $ q=\dfrac{a^3+b^3}{m^2+n^2}$.

This problem is true when we change $m^2+n^2=m^3+n^3$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. $\frac{a^3+b^3}{m^2+n^2}$ will always be a rational number when $a$, $b$, $m$ and $n$ are integers

Comment: @tpb261 If q is a positive rational number it can be written as $\frac{a^3+b^3}{m^2+n^2}$ where $a,b,m,n$ are positive integers

Comment: The formula will be cumbersome. For more simple equation can be viewed there.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369846/integer-solutions-of-x3y3-z2/764127#764127

Comment: We can change $m^2+n^2=m^2+n^3$

Comment: And what's the point? You still need to solve this equation. And more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an obvious way to do this, and in fact you can take $a = b$, $m = n$. If $q = c/d$, simply take $a = b = c d$, and $m = n = c d^2$.