# $A^2 = B^3 + C^3$ Diophantine Equations

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Solve, given all unknowns are non-zero integers

$$\begin{align}a^2 &= b^3 + c^3 \\b^2 &= c^3 + d^3
\\c^2 &= d^3 + e^3\\d^2 &= e^3 + f^3\\e^2 &=f^3 + g^3
\\f^2 &= g^3 + a^3\end{align}$$

Any tips on solving this please?

I can solve a single equation $a^2=b^3+c^3$, but Im having trouble going the next step

Thanks

Comment: so, what are the solutions for $a^2 = b^3 + c^3$

Comment: Methods for solving $a^2=b^3 + c^3$ are here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369846/integer-solutions-of-x3y3-z2

Comment: For full symmetry, is it also missing $g^2=a^3+b^3$? Or is that last one supposed to be missing?

Comment: The last one is supposed to be missing, here is where the problem comes from https://benvitalenum3ers.wordpress.com/2017/02/04/a2-b3-c3/

Comment: Do you want to find ONE solution (which would be already difficult() , or ALL solutions ? It is even unclear whether a solution exists.

Comment: I would be happy with one solution, if it exists.  Im not sure if there is a solution either.

Comment: I have tried the parametrizations for $a^2=b^3+c^3$. Then, taking resultants from the remaining equations, I obtain a contradiction, i.e., the zero solution. However, there might be other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

By examining this mod powers of $2$, you can at the least conclude some lower bounds on the absolute value of these numbers and some fairly large powers of $2$ that they must be divisible by. If you follow the argument below and see some clever pattern I am missing, then the below might be workable into an argument that no solutions exist.

Mod $2$, you have $x^n\equiv x$ for all $n$. So the system is: $$
\begin{align}
a &\equiv b + c &
b &\equiv c + d &
c &\equiv d + e&
d &\equiv e + f&
e &\equiv f + g&
f &\equiv g + a
\end{align}$$

Summing all the equations gives $a+b+c+d+e+f\equiv a+b$, which reduces to $c+d\equiv e+f$. Adding to the fourth equation, $c\equiv0$. Then the first, second and third equations say $a\equiv b\equiv d\equiv e$. Then the fourth equation says $f\equiv 0$, so the fifth equation says $g$ is also equivalent to $a\equiv b\equiv d\equiv e$.

So $c$ and $f$ are even for sure. And either all other values are even or all other values are odd.

Mod $8$, any odd number squared is $1$. Any odd number cubed is itself. And any even number cubed is $0$. So if $a,b,d,e,g$ are all odd, then mod $8$ the system is:$$
\begin{align}
1 &\equiv b&
1 &\equiv d&
c^2 &\equiv d + e&
1 &\equiv e&
1 &\equiv g&
f^2 &\equiv g + a
\end{align}$$

But this is an impossibility when you consider that the second, third, and fourth equations imply $c^2\equiv2$ which has no solutions mod $8$.

So all seven values are even. Mod $2^3$, the system is $$
\begin{align}
a^2 &\equiv 0&
b^2 &\equiv 0&
c^2 &\equiv 0&
d^2 &\equiv 0&
e^2 &\equiv 0&
f^2 &\equiv 0
\end{align}$$

which implies $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are all divisible by $2^2$. Note that the last two original equations then force $g$ to be divisible by $2^2$. Then mod $2^6$, the system is:$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &\equiv 0&
b^2 &\equiv 0&
c^2 &\equiv 0&
d^2 &\equiv 0&
e^2 &\equiv 0&
f^2 &\equiv 0
\end{align}$$

which implies $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are all divisible by $2^3$. Then mod $2^9$, the system is:$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &\equiv 0&
b^2 &\equiv 0&
c^2 &\equiv 0&
d^2 &\equiv 0&
e^2 &\equiv g^3&
f^2 &\equiv g^3
\end{align}$$

which implies $a,b,c,d,$ are all divisible by $2^5$. Note the original third equation says $e^3=c^2-d^3$ which is divisible by $2^{10}$, so $e$ is divisible by $2^4$. And then the original fourth equation says $f^3=d^2-e^3$, which is divisible by $2^{10}$. So $f$ is also divisible by $2^4$. And then the original fifth equation says $g^3=e^2-f^3$, divisible by $2^8$. So $g$ is divisible by $2^3$. Then $e^2=f^3+g^3$ is divisible by $2^9$, so $e$ is divisible by $2^5$. Then $g^3=e^2-f^3$ is divisible by $2^{10}$, so $g$ is divisible by $2^4$. The sixth original equation similarly gives that $f$ is divisible by $2^5$. In summary to this point, $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are all divisible by $2^5$ and $g$ is divisible by $2^4$.

OK, now mod $2^{15}$, the system is:$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &\equiv 0&
b^2 &\equiv 0&
c^2 &\equiv 0&
d^2 &\equiv 0&
e^2 &\equiv g^3&
f^2 &\equiv g^3
\end{align}$$

Note the growth in the power of $2$ in the modulus. And we have the same reduced system as a short while ago. We can immediately conclude $a,b,c,d$ are divisible by $2^8$. With similar pencil pushing as from the previous round, we can find higher powers of $2$ dividing $e,f$ as well. I'm too out of steam to type it up, but $e$ and $f$ can be proved to be divisible by $2^6$.

Then yet another round of this approach (mod $2^{18}$) leaves me with $a,b,c,d$ divisible by $2^9$, $e,f$ divisible by $2^6$, and $g$ divisible by $2^4$.

More and more of this approach keeps raising the powers of $2$ dividing the values. I've gotten up to $a,b$ divisible by $2^{21}$, $c,d$ by $2^{14}$, $e,f$ by $2^{9}$, $g$ by $2^{6}$ and I'm calling it quits even though I know it will go higher.

Either there is a pattern to capture and then make an inductive infinite ascent argument that no solutions exist; or at the worst if you keep up with this pencil-pushing you will know some large powers of $2$ that must divide each value.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I like your approach.  I need to read it closely to make sure I understand it.  One thing I have noticed is that when solving $a^2=b^3+c^3, abs(a)>abs(b), and abs(a)>abs(c).  If you follow this through all of the equations you end up with abs(a)>abs(b)>abs(c)>abs(d)>abs(e)>abs(f)>abs(g).  To circle back to a in the last equation its required that abs(g)>abs(a) - but this is inconsistent with the previous assertion.  A solution is looking unlikely

Comment: "One thing I have noticed is that when solving a^2=b^3+c^3, abs(a)>abs(b), and abs(a)>abs(c)." I don't understand this, unless there is some non-obvious proof. What if $b$ is very large positive and $c$ is just a little smaller in magnitude but negative? Then $|a|$ could be smaller than both $|b|$ and $|c|$.